# Changing the value in customtkinter CTKEntry placeholder during program execution

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

I am working on a program in PyCharm that will allow a user to either enter a value in a ctkENTRY box or press a button(s) to change the value.  I can use a variable to set the placeholder value when the program runs, but I would like it to update if the user decides to press a button instead.  I'm just starting to code the buttons and right now only have the motor speed buttons ("faster" and "slower") coded.  I tried to google an answer, but can't find anything, so I tried putting the following line in the button_event code for buttonNum 1

`self.entry_speed = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame, placeholder_text=speed)`

But that didn't seem to affect anything.

I did verify that the code is changing the "speed" variable by printing out the variable and observing it change in debug mode.

Is this even possible to do?

[image: Initial run]

After pressing the "faster" button.

[image: After pressing faster button]

Here's the code.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

# instantiate
config = ConfigParser()

# parse existing file
config.read('config.ini')

# read values from a section
speed = int(config.get('settings', 'speed'))
direction = config.get('settings', 'direction')
feed_steps = config.getint('settings', 'feed_steps')

print(f"current settings")
print(f"speed set to", speed)
print(f"Motor direction is ", direction)
print(f"Feeding steps is ", feed_steps)


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        global speed
        global direction
        global feed_steps


        #   Begin row count
        r = 0

        #   Set column to 0
        c = 0

        #   Set direction
        current_direction = f"Clockwise"

        #   Set steps per feeding
        current_steps_feeding = 200

        # configure window
        self.title("Motor Options")
        self.geometry(f"{750}x{385}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=750, corner_radius=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=c, rowspan=3, sticky="nsew")
        #        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(9, weight=1)

        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Motor Options",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=r, column=c, columnspan=4, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        r += 1
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Speed",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Speed up
        c += 1
        self.button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(1))
        self.button_1.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Speed down
        c += 1
        self.button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(2))
        self.button_2.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # create Speed entry box
        c += 1
        self.entry_speed = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame, placeholder_text=speed)
        self.entry_speed.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Direction
        c = 0
        r += 1
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Direction",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Clockwise
        c += 1
        self.button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(3))
        self.button_3.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Counter Clockwise
        c += 1
        self.button_4 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(4))
        self.button_4.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # create direction entry
        c += 1
        self.entry_direction = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame, placeholder_text=direction)
        self.entry_direction.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per Feeding
        c = 0
        r += 1
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Steps per Feeding",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per feed +100
        c += 1
        self.button_5 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(5))
        self.button_5.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per feed +10
        c += 1
        self.button_6 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(6))
        self.button_6.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per feed +1
        c += 1
        self.button_7 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(7))
        self.button_7.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # create steps per feeding box
        c = 0
        r += 1
        self.entry_speed = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame, placeholder_text=feed_steps)
        self.entry_speed.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per feed -100
        c += 1
        self.button_8 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(8))
        self.button_8.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per feed -10
        c += 1
        self.button_9 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(9))
        self.button_9.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Steps per feed -1
        c += 1
        self.button_10 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(10))
        self.button_10.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Test
        c = 0
        r += 1
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Test",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Test feed
        c += 1
        self.button_11 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(11))
        self.button_11.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Run motor
        c += 1
        self.button_12 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(12))
        self.button_12.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Stop motor
        c += 1
        self.button_13 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(13))
        self.button_13.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Save/Reset/Cancel
        c = 0
        r += 1
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Save changes
        r += 1
        c += 1
        self.button_14 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(14))
        self.button_14.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Reset
        c += 1
        self.button_15 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(15))
        self.button_15.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        #   Cancel
        c += 1
        self.button_16 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, command=lambda: self.button_event(16))
        self.button_16.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        self.button_1.configure(text="Faster")
        self.button_2.configure(text="Slower")
        self.button_3.configure(text="CW")
        self.button_4.configure(text="CCW")
        self.button_5.configure(text="+100")
        self.button_6.configure(text="+10")
        self.button_7.configure(text="+1")
        self.button_8.configure(text="-100")
        self.button_9.configure(text="-10")
        self.button_10.configure(text="-1")
        self.button_11.configure(text="Feed Test")
        self.button_12.configure(text="Run Motor")
        self.button_13.configure(text="Stop Motor")
        self.button_14.configure(text="Save")
        self.button_15.configure(text="Reset")
        self.button_16.configure(text="Cancel")

    def button_event(self, buttonNum):
        global speed

        if buttonNum == 1:
            print(f"Faster")
            if 0 <= speed < 100:
                speed += 1
                print(speed)
                self.entry_speed = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame, placeholder_text=speed)
        elif buttonNum == 2:
            print(f"Slower")
            if speed > 0 and speed < 101:
                speed -= 1
                print(speed)
        elif buttonNum == 3:
            print(f"CW")
        elif buttonNum == 4:
            print(f"CCW")
        elif buttonNum == 5:
            print(f"+100")
        elif buttonNum == 6:
            print(f"+10")
        elif buttonNum == 7:
            print(f"+1")
        elif buttonNum == 8:
            print(f"-100")
        elif buttonNum == 9:
            print(f"-10")
        elif buttonNum == 10:
            print(f"-1")
        elif buttonNum == 11:
            print(f"Feed Test")
        elif buttonNum == 12:
            print(f"Run Motor")
        elif buttonNum == 13:
            print(f"Stop Motor")
        elif buttonNum == 14:
            print(f"Save")
        elif buttonNum == 15:
            print(f"Reset")
        elif buttonNum == 16:
            print(f"Cancel")
            sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

And here's the config.ini file.

```
speed: 10
direction = CW
feed_steps: 150
```

Comment: Note that you have used same variable `self.entry_speed` for two instances of `CTkEntry`.  Also you should not create new instance of `CTkEntry` inside `button_event()`, use `self.entry_speed.configure(...)` to update the widget.

Comment: Thanks, removed the extra set and removed the new instance inside of the button_even().  I placed the ```self.entry_speed.configure(speed)``` in the button_event after the speed is incremented ```speed += 1```.  But I'm still not getting any update in the placeholder.

Comment: It should be `self.entry_speed.configure(placeholder_text=speed)` instead if you want to change the `placeholde_text` option.  But I wonder why it is `placeholder_text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following issues in your code:

- same variable `self.entry_speed` used for two instances of `CTkEntry`.  Use separate variables instead.
- create new instance of `CTkEntry` inside `button_event()`. Use `.configure()` to update existing widget instead.

```py
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # create steps per feeding box
        c = 0
        r += 1
        # use another instance variable for this entry
        self.entry_feeding = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame, placeholder_text=feed_steps)
        self.entry_feeding.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        ...

    def button_event(self, buttonNum):
        global speed

        if buttonNum == 1:
            print(f"Faster")
            if 0 <= speed < 100:
                speed += 1
                print(speed)
                # use .configure() to update widget option
                self.entry_speed.configure(placeholder_text=speed)
        elif buttonNum == 2:
            print(f"Slower")
            if speed > 0 and speed < 101:
                speed -= 1
                print(speed)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was too easy.  Guess I like to make things to convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

.configure(=<your text/variable>)

self.entry_speed.configure(placeholder-text=speed) would work to update the placeholder.

If you wanted to just insert the text so it's editable rather than just placeholder, you can use:
self.entry_speed.insert('0', speed)

0 is the index location, then the variable/text follows.